# Apostrophe with job titles

Tags: apostrophe

Do we use apostrophes when talking about a job position within a company?

Example:
IDB's director John
or
IDB director John

Thanks

Comment: Both are correct and idiomatic. The version without " 's " sounds more formal.

Comment: There are a lot of subtleties, such as where the focus of the sentence is: "The BBC's cleaners are on strike" (talking about the organisation), but "BBC cleaners are very skilled people" (talking about the cleaners).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you are including the name of the company as part of the person's job title, or if you are speaking about the company first and their director or employee as something belonging to them.

For example, 'BBC Director Tim Davie' sounds correct. It is though 'BBC Director' is his job title.

However, when speaking about the corporation we'd normally use an article and say "*the BBC*", and this might be an occasion where we'd use a possessive apostrophe and say "*the BBC's director Tim Davie*". So, it could also depend on what the company name is, or what the initialism stands for.

Note that, job titles may be capitalised (ie 'Director' with a capital D), but if you are referring to *a* director of a company then it would not.